# CSS - align text to div

Tags: html, asp.net, css, alignment

I'm struggling with aligning text to div.

I currently have this:

[image]

But I want to achieve this (I have just edited a screenshot to show you what I mean):

[image]

My code looks as follows:

**HTML**

```
<div class="regionHeader">
    <div class="regionArrow"></div>
    <h2>Some long header that should be aligned to the left next to the div with arrow</h2>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.regionHeader {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #ffd800;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.regionArrow {
    border-right: 4px solid #ffd800;
    border-bottom: 4px solid #ffd800;
    width: 13px;
    height: 13px;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    float: left;
    margin-top: 11px;
    margin-right: 13px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 3px;
}

h2 {
    font-family: changa-regular;
    font-size: 2em;
}
```

I have already played with display and floats, but it either doesn't work or I'm doing it incorrectly.

Comment: Someone’s probably gonna propose a flexbox solution soon … but I would simply absolutely position the arrow in such a case, and give the parent some padding-left.

Comment: Or, if you want to keep what you have, with the floating - just add `overflow:hidden` for the `h2`.

Comment: I've prepared JS Fiddle for you Kacper: https://jsfiddle.net/c6k28wLx/. Have fun :) Best regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can either simply use a `padding-left` on your heading:

```css
.regionHeader {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffd800;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.regionArrow {
  border-right: 4px solid #ffd800;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ffd800;
  width: 12px;
  height: 13px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  float: left;
  margin-top: 11px 13px 0 3px;
}

h2 {
  font-size: 2em;
  padding-left: 1.2em; /* <- added */
}
```

```html
<div class="regionHeader">
  <div class="regionArrow"></div>
  <h2>Some long header that should be aligned to the left next to the div with arrow</h2>
</div>
```

Or use a flexbox approach and remove the `float`.

```css
.regionHeader {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ffd800;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: flex; /* <- added */
}

.regionArrow {
  border-right: 4px solid #ffd800;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #ffd800;
  width: 16px;
  height: 13px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  margin: 30px 15px;
}

h2 {
  font-family: changa-regular;
  font-size: 2em;
}
```

```html
<div class="regionHeader">
  <div class="regionArrow"></div>
  <h2>Some long header that should be aligned to the left next to the div with arrow</h2>
</div>
```

[Browser support for flexbox](https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) is pretty good. Don't forget to add proper vendor prefixes.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Flexbox feels better to me, but I think I will go for padding due to the fact that flexbox has limited support with older browsers.

Comment: Flexbox is widely supported nowadays. You should include vendor prefixes, though. [This](https://autoprefixer.github.io/) online tool generate prefixes for you. [That one](http://algid.com/Flex-Designer) add vendor prefixes to `flexbox` layouts as well.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, @MarioVázquez! Updated my answer accordingly.